# Django Rest - Include serializer object in get_*** method

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to include a related model's serialized object in another serializer's customized object but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have two models - snippet and user.  Snippet model has user's foreign keys.  What I need is to include snippet's serialized object in the "get_included" method of UserSerializer and make UserSerializer to return a JSON object like this:

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "included": [
      {'id': 2,'created': "20150729" },
      {'id': 3,'created': "20150730" }, 
   ]
}
```

The below is my code.

```
# Snippet Model
from django.db import models
class Snippet(models.Model):
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')

# Snippet serializer
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   model = Snippet
   fields = ('id','created')

# User serializer
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  included = serializers.SerilizerMethodField()
  class Meta: 
     model = User
     depth = 1 
     fields = ('id','included')

  def get_included(self, obj):
     snippets = SnippetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True).data

     return snippets
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `get_included` method. Simply add the `snippets` attribute to the class.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    included = SnippetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta: 
        model = User
        depth = 1 
        fields = ('id','included')
```

Comment: I am following JSON API structure (http://jsonapi.org/) and I need to be able to include a related model's serialized object under "include" attribute.  Sorry. I didn't explain my requirement clearly.

Comment: you can name that attribute whatever you want, just assign the `SnippetSerializer` to it.

Comment: Is there any way to include multiple serialized objects of other models? like {"id":1, "included":[{"id":2,"created":"2015","type":"snippet"}, {"id"2", created":"2015","type":"comment"}]}

Comment: To do that I think you would have to merge the querysets in the view and create a polymorphic serializer to handle multiple types.